# Interaction UI and Java Code

Tags: java, javabeans, spring-webflow

Hy Folks,

ok, (for me) my problem is hard to explain but I guess for most of you it will seem pretty trivial. I'm building an application using spring webflow. The users have to type in their username in the webapp, which is then stored in a bean. When they click on the button "login" a method of the bean ( `connect()` ) is called, which than establishes a jms connection to a another server.

```
public class HumanBrokerBean implements Serializable {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** The broker name. */
    private String brokerName;

    /** The password. */
    private String password;

    private double cashPosition = 0;



    /**
     * Gets the password.
     * 
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the password.
     * 
     * @param password
     *            the new password
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the broker name.
     * 
     * @return the broker name
     */
    public String getBrokerName() {
        return brokerName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the broker name.
     * 
     * @param brokerName
     *            the new broker name
     */
    public void setBrokerName(String brokerName) {
        this.brokerName = brokerName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the cashPosition
     */
    public double getCashPosition() {
        return cashPosition;
    }


        public boolean connect(){

         ConnectionService connection = new ConnectionService();
         //if there have been problems while establishing the connection
         if(!connection.connect(username, password, serverConnection, byPass)){
            return false;
        }
        //if connection was established
        return true;
    }

}
```

After some time a message from the remote server arrives saying that the CashPosition of a particular user has changed. Now I will have to update the variable "cashPosition" of the Bean whcih than should be displayed in the UI.

1) My Problem is that I simply can't access the the values of the bean. How can I manage to access them?

2) After some time the user may want to send a message to the server. For this reason I have a method inside my ConnectionService Class. Now I wanted to create a method in the Bean that should mediate between the UI and the ConnectionService. Here I have the problem, that I can't create a class variable and an according method like

```
private Connection Service connection;

public void sendMessage(String message){
    connection.send(message);
}
```

because some elements of the class Connection Service aren't serializable (ActiveMQ). That's why I tried it in this way:

```
public void sendMessage(String message){
    ConnectionService connection = new ConenctionService();
    connection.send(message);
}
```

But this solution always creates a new instance of the class connection service, which doesn't work here because of ActiveMQ... So I have to be able to access this class from my bean but I'M not sure how.

I hope that I colud make you my problem clear...

Any help is highly apprechiated!

Answer (score 0):

You could put your `connection` as a class variable as you tried, but mark it with the `transient` keyword to prevent it from being serialized, like this:

```
private transient Connection Service connection;
```

Just be aware that if the bean is ever deserialized, the `connection` will be null - so you either need to check for this, or provide a custom `private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;` method that performs the default deserialization, then re-creates the connection.  (Additional details available at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html .)

Comment: mhm, thanks for the answer but I'm not sure if this is going to solve my problem. Altough I've read pretty much about (spring)beans, I'm pretty new to it. My main question really is: How am I able to access/manipulate the content of a bean, that has been created programmatically? In other words: how does the connection between "normal" java code and beans look like?